# Fourier transform of $1/|x|^{\alpha}$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

My problem is to prove the following identity:
$$C_{\alpha}\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{1}{|x|^\alpha} \phi(x) dx = C_{n-\alpha}\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{1}{|x|^{n-\alpha}} \widehat{\phi}(x) dx$$
where $\phi:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb C$ is on the Schwartz space  , $0<\alpha <n$, $C_{\beta} = \Gamma(\beta/2)/\pi^{\beta/2}$ and $$\widehat{\phi}(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \phi(y)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot y}dy.$$

In other words, how to calculate fourier transform of $1/|x|^\alpha$?

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1614685/118300 ! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denoting by $\widehat{\cdot}$ the Fourier transform in $\mathbb R^d$ and letting
$$
f_\lambda(x)\equiv f(\lambda x),
$$ 
then, by definition of the Fourier transform,
\begin{align}
\widehat {f_\lambda}(k)&=\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{-ik\cdot x}f(\lambda x)dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{-ik\cdot x/\lambda}f(x)\lambda^{-d}dx\\
&=\lambda^{-d}\widehat f(k/\lambda).
\end{align}
Let $f(x)=F(|x|)$ be a radial function;
if $M\in SO(d)$, then $f_M(x)\equiv f(Mx)=f(x)$ and hence, since $\widehat{ f_M}(k)=\widehat f(Mk)$, we have $\widehat {f_M}= \widehat f$, which in turn implies that also $\widehat f$ is radial. Now, suppose $f(x)=|x|^{-\alpha}$, for $0<\alpha<d$, then 
$$
f_\lambda(x) = \lambda^{-\alpha}f(x)
$$
and, by the above remark,
$$
\widehat f (k/\lambda)= \lambda^{d}\widehat {f_\lambda}(k) = \lambda^{d-\alpha}\hat f(k).
$$
The only radial $\widehat f$ homogeneous of degree $-d+\alpha$ is 
$$
\widehat f (k) = |k|^{\alpha-d},
$$
up to constants.

Note that $f$ can be split as the sum of two pieces: let $B_a$ be the ball of radius $a$ centred at the origin, then
\begin{align}
f&\equiv u+v\\
&=
\chi_{B_a}(x)\frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}}+\left(1-\chi_{B_a}(x)\right)\frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}};
\end{align}
$u$ lies in $L^1(\mathbb R^d)$, for $0<\alpha<d$, and $v$ lies in $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$, for $\alpha>d/2$. This ensures $\widehat u \in L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ and $\widehat v\in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ and that $\widehat f$ needs indeed to be a function in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^d)$ from an abstract point of view.
So $f,\widehat f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^d)$.

More generally, $f$ lies in $\mathscr S'(\mathbb R^d)$, which is stable under Fourier transform.

Comment: Nice trick! But there is something bothering me. Taking $f(x) = 1/|x|^\alpha$ we have that $\widehat{f}$ is a distribution on $S'$. I totally agree that it's homogeneous of degree $-d+ \alpha$ and invariant by action of $SO(n)$. But why does this implies that $\widehat{f}$ is of the form $c/|x|^{d-\alpha}$? I agree that if $\widehat{f}$ is a function then $\widehat{f}(x) = \widehat f(|x|e) =|x|^{-d+\alpha} \widehat f(e)$ where $e$ is a unitary vector, but i can't see why $\widehat f$ is a function.

Comment: @HugoC.Botós Good point, overlooked that. I have a strong belief that this statement also holds for tempered distribution, though.

Comment: @HugoC.Botós I added a remark concerning your observation. Let me know!

Comment: I just asked a question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619691/why-does-fourier-transform-of-1-x-alpha-is-a-function
I belive there is a way of prove that without the restriction  $2\alpha>d$. Thanks for making that observation.

Comment: Why f is a tempered distribution?

Comment: @Brightsun What is your definition of the Fourier transform? $e^{-xy}$ or $e^{-2\pi I ixy}$

Comment: @BobOakley I guess I used $e^{-ikx}$ judging from the second equation in the post...

Comment: @Brightsun Thx. I have another question. How to get the Fourier transform of the $1/|x|^2$ for 2 dimension?  Or can we get a similar formula that $\int_{R^2}\hat{p}(\xi)\hat{q}(\xi)|\xi|^{-2}d\xi= A\int_{R^2}\int_{R^2}p(x) q(y) (-\log|x-y|)dxdy$?

Comment: @BobOakley Once you have the answer as a function of $\xi$ for generic $D$ you can obtain the answer for $D=2$ by analytic continuation. Letting $D=2+\epsilon$, expand for small $\epsilon$ and you should find a $\xi$-independent pole $1/\epsilon$, plus a finite term proportional to $\log|\xi|$.

Comment: @Brightsun Sorry, I am confused. What is your $D$? And how to find such $\xi$?

Comment: @Hermi The Fourier transform of $1/|x|^2$ in dimension $2$ is computed here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723136/the-fourier-transform-of-1-p3

Answer (score 4):

Following Brightsun solution we have $\widehat f (\xi) = k/|\xi|^{n-\alpha}$. Let $g(x) = e^{-\pi x^2}$, we have $\widehat g = g$. Since
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} \widehat{f}(x)g(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x)\widehat{g}(x)dx,$$
we have
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{k}{|x|^{n-\alpha}}e^{-\pi x^2}dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{1}{|x|^\alpha}e^{-\pi x^2}dx.$$
In polar coordinates we have:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}}e^{-\pi x^2}dx = \sigma(\mathbb S^{n-1})\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\pi r^2}r^{n-1}}{r^{\alpha}} = \sigma(S^{n-1})\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\pi r^2}r^{n-1-\alpha} dr,$$
where $\sigma$ is the measure on the sphere. Taking $u = \pi r^2$ we obtain
$$
\sigma(S^{n-1})\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\pi r^2}r^{n-1-\alpha} dr 
= 
\frac{\sigma(S^{n-1})}{2\pi^{(n-\alpha)/2}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{\frac{n-\alpha}{2} -1} e^{-u}du 
= 
\frac{\sigma(S^{n-1})\Gamma(\frac{n-\alpha}{2})}{2\pi^{(n-\alpha)/2}}.$$
Analogously, we can deduce
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{k}{|x|^{n-\alpha}}e^{-\pi x^2}dx 
= 
\frac{k\sigma(S^{n-1})\Gamma(\alpha/2)}{2\pi^{\alpha/2}}$$
and we have
$$
k
=
\frac{\Gamma((n-\alpha)/2)\pi^{\alpha/2}}{\Gamma(\alpha/2)\pi^{(n-\alpha)/2}}.$$
Therefore, the identity
$$C_{\alpha}\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{1}{|x|^\alpha} \phi(x) dx = C_{n-\alpha}\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{1}{|x|^{n-\alpha}} \widehat{\phi}(x) dx$$
holds.

Comment: Nice! Do you think this method also resolves the controversy in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341370/fundamental-solution-to-the-laplace-equation-by-fourier-transform ? I didn't think of it to be honest...

Comment: I think it works fine with direct calculation in the case $d>3$. I belive that de critical case in the identity in my question works with use $log |x|$ in the place of $1/|x|^{\alpha} $ in the case that $d=\alpha $. That would prove the result to d=2.

Comment: Why are we able to use $$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} \widehat{f}(x)g(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x)\widehat{g}(x)dx, $$ when $f(x)=|x|^{-\alpha}$ does not satisfy $$ \sup_{x \in R^d}|x^a\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^bf(x) | < \infty$$ specifically for $a>\alpha$ and $b=0$. In Stein's Fourier Analysis text, both $f$ and $g$ need to satisfy that sup condition in order to use the identity in question.

Comment: This identity works in several levels of generality. You can take $f$ and $g$ in $L^1$ and the identity is true by Lemma 8.25 of Folland's Real Analysis book (2nd edition). You also can use $f$ and $g$ in $L^2$ or $f\in S'$ and $g \in S$.

Comment: In the last case you have to write the identity in the language of tempered distribution.

Comment: I think it is noteworthy that you are using a different definition of the Fourier transformation than Brightsun does in his comment, thus coming to a different conclusion what the exact constant should be.