# The Fourier transform of $1/p^3$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, fourier-transform

The Fourier transforms we use are
\begin{align}
\tilde{f}(\mathbf{p})&=\int d^3x\,f(\mathbf{x})
 e^{-i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\\[5pt]
f(\mathbf{x})&=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\,\tilde{f}(\mathbf{p})
 e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}}
\end{align}
I want to calculate the transfom of $1/p^3$
\begin{align}
I=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\,\frac{1}{p^3}
 e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}}
\end{align}

Comment: Where $p=|\mathbf{p}|,$ I suppose.

Comment: @ md2perpe, yes

Comment: I think it's important to clarify what do you mean by $1/\vert p\vert^3$; the function is not locally integrable and it doesn't have a direct interpretation as a distribution. You can define the distribution $1/t_+$ in $\mathbb{R}$ using integration by parts and the identity $\partial\log t = 1/t$ for $t>0$, so $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}\phi(t)\,dt := -\int_0^\infty \log t\partial_t\phi\,dt$. We can carry this definition to your case as $\int\frac{1}{p^3}\phi := \int\frac{\log p}{p^2}\partial_r\phi$. By your notation I suspect you're a physicists studying QFT.

Comment: @user90189. Formally taking the Laplacian of the expression gives
$$\begin{align}
-\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\,\frac{1}{p}
 e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}}
\end{align}$$
which is locally integrable and thus defines a distribution. That would at least take us a bit to a solution.

Comment: @md2perpe Nice! Formally the Fourier transform would be, up to a constant, $-\Delta^{-1}\frac{1}{\vert x\vert^2} = \frac{1}{\vert x\vert}*\frac{1}{\vert x\vert^2}$. We cannot define it directly as the Schwartz distribution $\langle \frac{1}{\vert x\vert^2},-\Delta^{-1}\phi\rangle$ because $-\Delta^{-1}\phi$ doesn't decay rapidly. Some modification is needed.

Comment: I've done some calculations and get 
$$
A + \frac{B}{|\mathbf{x}|} + C \frac{\ln |\mathbf{x}|}{|\mathbf{x}|^2}
$$
but do not know the constants $A,B,C.$

Comment: I made a modification, Fourier transform $$ \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}e^{-\mu p}\frac{1}{p^3}e^{-i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}} $$, and then take $\mu\rightarrow 0$ limit, the result is something like $$-\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\ln |\mathbf{x}|+{\rm constant}$$

Comment: @user90189. You are right mostly. My major is hep-th.

Comment: Use maths notation not physics

Comment: I thought [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943) solution I posted on the 1-D Fourier Transform of $|x|^s$, $s\in \mathbb{R}$ and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4113196#4113196) on the 1-D Fourier Transform of $\log(|x|)$ might be of interest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short, in $\mathbb{R}^d$, if I define the Fourier transform as $\mathcal{F}(f)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(y) \,e^{-2iπxy}\,\mathrm{d}y$ the result is
$$
\boxed{\mathcal{F}\!\left(\frac{1}{\omega_d\,|x|^d}\right) = \frac{\psi(d/2)-\gamma}{2} - \ln(|πx|)}
$$
where $\omega_d = \frac{2\,\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}$ is the size of the unit sphere (so $\omega_3 = 4\pi$), $\gamma$ is Euler–Mascheroni constant and $\psi$ is the digamma function. Since $\psi(3/2) = 2-\gamma-\ln(4)$, we deduce that in dimension $3$
$$
\mathcal{F}\!\left(\frac{1}{4\pi\,|x|^3}\right) = 1-\gamma -\ln(|2πx|)
$$
which with your Fourier transform convention gives
$$
\boxed{\tilde{\mathcal{F}}\!\left(\frac{1}{|x|^3}\right) = \frac{1-\gamma -\ln(|x|)}{2\pi^2}.}
$$

---

Now the details. So first, what is the meaning of $\frac{1}{|x|^d}$? One can define the following distribution
$$
v_d := \mathrm{pf}\!\left(\frac{1}{|x|^d}\right) := \mathrm{div}\!\left(\frac{x\ln(|x|)}{|x|^d}\right)
$$
where the derivative is taken in the sense of distributions. One easily verifies that the distribution $v_d$ coincides on $\Bbb R^d\setminus\{0\}$ with the function
$$
v_d(x) = \frac{1}{|x|^d} \text{ for any } x≠ 0.
$$
One also notices that it is a tempered distribution as the derivative of a function in $L^1 + L^\infty$.

---

Let $u_d = \frac{x\ln(|x|)}{|x|^d}$. Multiplying by a test function $\varphi\in C^\infty_c$, one gets for any $\lambda>0$
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle v_d,\varphi\rangle &= -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} u_d\cdot\nabla\varphi
\\
&= -\int_{|x|\leq\lambda} u_d\cdot\nabla(\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)) - \int_{|x|>\lambda} u_d\cdot\nabla \varphi
\end{align*}
$$
which by integration by parts yields
$$
\begin{align}\tag{1}\label{eq1}
\langle v_d,\varphi\rangle &= \int_{|x|\leq\lambda} \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|^d}\,\mathrm{d}x
\\
&\quad+ \int_{|x|>\lambda} \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|^d} \,\mathrm{d}x + \omega_d \ln(\lambda) \,\varphi(0).
\end{align}
$$
One can take $\lambda = 1$ to get
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle v_d,\varphi\rangle &= \int_{|x|\leq 1} \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|^d}\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{|x|> 1} \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|^d} \,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
$$
But with the formula \eqref{eq1} with $\lambda\neq 1$, one can also compute easily the distribution $v_d(\lambda x)$ defined by
$$
\langle v_d(\lambda x),\varphi(x)\rangle = \frac{1}{|\lambda|^d}\langle v_d(x),\varphi(x/\lambda)\rangle
$$
using Equation \eqref{eq1} with $\varphi(x)$ replaced by $\varphi(x/\lambda)$. Doing the change of variable $x/\lambda \to x$ yields
$$
v_d(\lambda\,\cdot) = \frac{1}{|\lambda|^d}\,v_d + \omega_d\frac{\ln(\lambda)}{|\lambda|^d}\,\delta_0.
$$
Therefore, we can now use the scaling properties of the Fourier transform to get for any $r=1/\lambda>0$
$$
\begin{align*}
(\mathcal{F}(v_d))(r\tilde{x}) &= r^{-d} (\mathcal{F}(v_d(y/r)))(\tilde{x}) 
\\&= \mathcal{F}(v_d-\omega_d\ln(r)\delta_0)(\tilde{x})
\\&= \mathcal{F}(v_d)(\tilde{x}) -\omega_d\ln(r).
\end{align*}
$$
Taking $\tilde{x} = \frac{x}{|x|}$ and $r=|x|$ gives
$$
\boxed{\mathcal{F}(v_d)(x) = C_d -\omega_d\ln(|x|)}
$$
where $C_d = \mathcal{F}(v_d)(\tilde{x})$ is a constant since the Fourier transform of a radial function is radial.

---

If you want to know the constant $C_d$, the usual trick is to multiply by a Gaussian and use the fact that we know the Fourier transform of a Gaussian. Here remark first that by the Fourier inversion theorem we have
$$
\mathcal{F}(\ln(|x|)) = C_d\, \delta_0 - \frac{v_d}{\omega_d}
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align*}
 C_d - \langle\mathcal{F}(\ln(|x|)), e^{-\pi|x|^2}\rangle &= \frac{1}{\omega_d}\langle v_d, e^{-\pi|x|^2}\rangle
 \\
 &= \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-\pi r^2}-1}{r}\,\mathrm{d} r + \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-\pi r^2}}{r}\,\mathrm{d} r
 \\
 &= \int_0^\pi \frac{e^{-t}-1}{2\,t}\,\mathrm{d} t + \int_\pi^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{2\,t}\,\mathrm{d} t
 \\
 &= \frac{-\ln(\pi)}{2} + \int_0^\pi \frac{\ln(t)\,e^{-t}}{2}\,\mathrm{d} t + \int_\pi^\infty \frac{\ln(t)\,e^{-t}}{2}\,\mathrm{d} t
 \\
 &= \frac{-\gamma - \ln(\pi)}{2}
\end{align*}
$$
where $\gamma = -\Gamma'(1) = -\psi(1)$ and I did a polar change of variable and the change $t = πr^2$ and then integrations by parts. But since $\mathcal{F}(e^{-\pi|x|^2}) = e^{-\pi|x|^2}$, we can also compute
$$
\begin{align*}
 \langle\mathcal{F}(\ln(|x|)), e^{-\pi|x|^2}\rangle &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \ln(|x|)\, e^{-\pi|x|^2}\,\mathrm{d} x
 \\
 &= \omega_d \int_0^\infty \ln(r)\,e^{-\pi r^2} r^{d-1}\,\mathrm{d} r
 \\
 &= \frac{1}{2\,\Gamma(d/2)} \int_0^\infty (\ln(t)-\ln(\pi))\,e^{-t}\, t^{d/2-1}\,\mathrm{d} t
 \\
 &= \frac{1}{2} \,\big(\psi(d/2) - \ln(\pi)\big).
\end{align*}
$$
with the same changes of variable. We deduce that $C_d = \frac{\psi(d/2)-\gamma}{2} - \ln(\pi)$. Tell me if you spot any errors!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Though I can not understand your process right now, I think your result is right. By the way, can you calculate the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|^\alpha}$ in general $d$ dimensions?

Comment: Yes, this one is more classical when $a \in (0,d)$ , then $\mathcal{F}(1/(\omega_a |x|^a)) = 1/(\omega_{d-a} |x|^{d-a})$

Comment: You can find the result in a lot of textbooks, for example "Functional Analysis" from Lieb and Loss. Then you can take derivatives to get the other cases. An other special case is the case when $a=-2n$ is a nonnegative integer. Then you get the Dirac delta if $n=0$ and powers of Laplacian of the Dirac delta when $n$ is larger.

Comment: @LL3.14 Hi LL!  I hope that you're doing well.  I always enjoy reading your posted solutions.  I thought [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943) solution I posted on the Fourier Transforms of $|x|^s$, $s\in \mathbb{R}$ and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4113196#4113196) on the Fourier Transform of $\log(|x|)$ might be of interest.

Comment: This is ingenuous. The end product is very polished. But I am very curious how you came up with the idea. I guess the process was a lot messier?