# Definition of $\frac{1}{|\xi|^2}$ as Distribution in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, fundamental-solution

I'm trying to understand the Fundamental solution of the Laplacian in two dimensions using Fourier Transform with Definition
$$\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x) e^{-i \xi \cdot x} dx .$$
So in theory all I have to do is calculate the (inverse) Fourier transform of $f(\xi) = \frac{1}{|\xi|^2}$, but how is $T_f(\varphi)$ defined, if $f$ is not locally integrable? Like if $\varphi(\xi) \geq 0 $ and $\varphi(\xi) = 1$ if $\xi \leq 1$ then the Integral over the unit ball does not converge.

Comment: $\frac{1}{|\xi|^2}$ is not locally integrable in $\Bbb{R}^2$, so one should "renormalize" it by "subtracting off an infinite multiple of a dirac delta" in order to obtained a temprerd distribution. For more details, I suggest you take a look at Folland's PDE book, Chapter 4B (particularly page 151, and Exercises 1 and 2). Alternatively, you can just go the simpler route, and show that $f(\xi)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|\xi|$ on $\Bbb{R}^2$ (which is locally integrable) is the fundamental solution (for this, see Theorem 2.17 in the same book). As a heads up, Folland uses a different FT convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bullet$ You can define it as the derivative in the sense of distributions of a locally integrable function, i.e. you can define the distribution $T$ by
$$
T := \mathrm{pf}\left(\frac{1}{|x|^2}\right) := \mathrm{div}\left(\frac{\ln(|x|)}{|x|^2} \,x\right).
$$
Then, $T(x) = \tfrac{1}{|x|^2}$ if $x≠ 0$ and as already detailed in my answer in [The Fourier transform of $1/p^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723136/the-fourier-transform-of-1-p3/3724502#3724502), it acts on test functions as
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle T,\varphi\rangle &= \int_{|x|\leq 1} \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|^2}\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{|x|> 1} \frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|^2} \,\mathrm{d}x,
\end{align*}
$$
and its Fourier transform in your convention is then
$$
\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{|x|^2}\right) = \ln(2)-\gamma - \ln(|x|).
$$

$\bullet$ In your case, it is important to notice that this is indeed an inverse of $|x|^2$ since
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle |x|^2\,T,\varphi\rangle &= \langle T,|x|^2\,\varphi\rangle
\\
&= \int_{|x|\leq 1} \frac{|x|^2\,\varphi(x)-|0|^2\varphi(0)}{|x|^2}\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{|x|> 1} \frac{|x|^2\,\varphi(x)}{|x|^2} \,\mathrm{d}x
\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R^2} \varphi(x)\,\mathrm d x = \langle 1,\varphi\rangle
\end{align*}
$$
so $|x|^2\,T = 1$ in the sense of distributions. Notice however that it is not the unique solution, as one can add $a\,\delta_0 + b\cdot\nabla\delta_0$. This is not a problem when solving the Laplace equation since solutions of the Laplace equation are also defined up to $a + b·x$.

Comment: Wow thanks! Just one more question: Does pf mean principle value or is it defined as $pf(f) = div(ln(|x| f(x) x)$ ?
Or can I look up the definition of pf?

Comment: The pf notation stands for finite part https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization