# Determining the principal value of $\frac{1}{\lvert\vec{x}-\vec{x}'\rvert^3}$

Tags: integration, cauchy-principal-value

I use the following definition of principal value:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)\left[h\right]=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\sum_{x_i|f(x_i)=0}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{x_i-\epsilon}dx\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}+\int_{x_i+\epsilon}^{+\infty}dx\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}\right]
\end{equation}
where $h$ is a test function.
With this definition I would like to compute
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}\left(\frac{1}{\lvert\vec{x}-\vec{x}'\rvert^3}\right)
\end{equation}
I am not sure how to compute it by using that definition. The ultimate goal for me is to compute this integral:
\begin{equation}
\int d^3x'\sqrt{g}\,\mathcal{P}\left(\frac{1}{\lvert\vec{x}-\vec{x}'\rvert^3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\lvert \vec{x}'\rvert^n}\right)
\end{equation}
where $n$ is a non negative integer and $g$ is the metric for a 3 dimensional flate space.
I could imagine to use spherical coordinates. Then I would have the integral:
\begin{equation}
2\pi\int dr'd\theta'\,r'^2\sin\theta'\mathcal{P}\left(\frac{1}{(r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\theta)^{3/2}}\right)\frac{1}{r^{'n}}
\end{equation}
but I don't know how to continue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what precisely you're trying to integrate. The expression with $\int d^3x'$ has a $\mathcal{P}$ inside the integral? And/or doesn't match the notation you begin with?

Comment: Yes, it is inside. Inside the integral I have $\mathcal{P}\left(\frac{1}{\lvert \vec{x}-\vec{x}'\rvert^3}\right)$ times $\left(\frac{1}{\lvert \vec{x}'\rvert^n}\right)$. I am not sure how I compute $\mathcal{P}\left(\frac{1}{\lvert \vec{x}-\vec{x}'\rvert^3}\right)$  using the definition

Comment: Is $g$ just $1$ here ?

Comment: You might be interested by my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723136/the-fourier-transform-of-1-p3/3724502#3724502

Comment: ok, I have a look at it. Anyway, yes, in cartesian coordinates g  should be just 1.

Comment: Notice also that your integral is a convolution so you might want to use the Fourier transform to solve it (or in certain cases just to give it a meaning) ... In particular if $0<a,n<3$, $|x|^{-a} * |x|^{-n} = c\,|x|^{d-(a+n)}$. But here this is a more critical case and the result might depend on the value of $n$ ...